# Can .ipa file be reverse engineered if you have the dSYM?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, ipa, dsym

Some code analysis tools require you to submit your .ipa along with your .dSYM file.

Is sending the .dSYM file along with the .ipa a risk for reverse-engineering of the app? I mean, can someone get to the source code if he has both the .ipa and the .dSYM?

Comment: Isn't the point of a code analysis tool to (partially) reverse-engineer your application in order to analyse it anyway? Also, out of curiosity, any examples of the tools you're talking about, for .ipa's?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing actully. I asked them about their process, like what exactly they're going to do with the .ipa and the .dSYM. Still waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that hard to reverse-engineer applications even without symbols.

Here's what recent versions of [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) can show you *without* the .dSYM:

[image: IDA iPhone Objective-C disassembly]

And if you have the Hex-Rays decompiler, you can get something like:

```
// CKMessagesController - (void)mailComposeController:(id) didFinishWithResult:(int) error:(id) 
void __cdecl -[CKMessagesController mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:](struct CKMessagesController *self, SEL a2, id a3, int a4, id a5)
{
  struct CKMessagesController *v5; // r4@1

  v5 = self;
  objc_msgSend(self, "dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:", 1, 0);
  objc_msgSend((void *)v5->_mailComposeController, "release");
  v5->_mailComposeController = 0;
}
```

Having the .dSYM will definitely make the task even easier: not only ALL the function and variable names will be there (including private ones), but probably the full types as well (structures, classes and enums). You won't be able to get the *source* code, but probably something pretty close to it.

Answer (score 2):

No he will not get the source-code, but knowing the symbol names might help understanding the compiled / decompiled code.